# How to add/delete footer links from magento 2.0.9 admin

Tags: magento2, admin, footer, magento-2.0.9

I am new to magento. I want to add a new link to the footer.

In some older versions I could see a menu called CMS through which admin can add footer links. But nothing like that is seen in `2.0.9 version`.

I referred many tutorials which says about direct editing of `default.xml` file.

**Is it possible to add a new footer link via admin?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: footer_links_block is not there in my Content -> Block. Is there any difference in magento 2.0.9 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like **the `footer_links_block` is gone in the newer version of M2**. So here's how to do it based on [this forum Q&A](https://community.magento.com/t5/Admin-Configuration-Questions/how-to-add-and-edit-the-footer-link-in-magento-2/td-p/39733):

### Create a block

Under **Content > Blocks** click the Add New Block button.

- Block Title: Footer Links Block
- Identifier: footer_links_block
- Store View: choose your store view
- Add your custom link list in the content. For example:

  ```
  <ul class="footer links">
      <li class="nav item"><a href="{{store url="link1"}">Link 1</a></li>
      <li class="nav item"><a href="{{store url="link2"}">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  ```
- Save

### Create a widget

Under **Content > Widgets**, click the Add Widget button.

- Type: CMS Block
- Design Package/Theme: choose your theme then click Continue
- Widget Title: Footer Links
- Assign to store views : choose your store view
- Click the Add Layout Update button and choose "Display on All Pages"
- In the container dropdown, choose "CMS Footer Links"
- In the "Widget options" tab on the left, click Select Block and choose your "Footer Links Block"
- Save

Don't forget to flush the cache.

Comment: A very elegant way to add this to the footer if you want to do it via admin! This way you avoid to use xml.